# Unable to start apache-tomcat

Tags: tomcat, solaris

I installed Solaris 10 on my machine, but noticed that `apache-tomcat` is in maintenance state.

I tried these commands but of no use:

```
svcadm clear apache-tomcat
svcadm enable apache-tomcat
```

The logs just say this:

```
Failed to start Tomcat...

[ Aug  2 01:12:10 Method "start" exited with status 1 ]
```

Can someone please help me troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: Got logs?  Probably `catalina.out`?

Comment: I am not able to find `catalina.out`.

Comment: you can try to start the daemon "manually" to see the output (not using the SMF service, but the command you can see in the service definition) and see the error messages  (e.g. /path/to/tomcat start)

Answer (score 0):

Review the logs for the FRMI in /var/svc/log/. To see where the logs are, run the following;

You should see output similar to the following;

```
server$ svcs -xv svc:/system/system-log:default | grep "/var/svc/log"
   See: /var/svc/log/system-system-log:default.log
server$
```

That will tell you why SMF is putting the service in maintenance-mode.

**EDIT:** Just saw your update. Okay, now to find out what the SMF manifest is doing when it's called with the `start` argument.

Look in `/var/svc/manifest` for a `*.xml` that has tomcat in the name and read the script and find out what it does.

Perhaps it's unable to create a log file due to a lack of permissions and *that* is what's causing the `start` to fail.